# repeated error: "Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init"

Tags: boot

In the past few weeks when I turned my computer on it wrote me this error:

> mount: mounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/280914ad-ed45-4948-bfdf-9
>
> ac440455635 on /root failed: Invalid argument
>
> mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: NO such file or directory
>
> mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: NO such file or directory
>
> mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: NO such file or directory
>
> Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
>
> No init found. Try passing init=bootarg.
>
> Busy Box v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built-in shell (ash) Enter
>
> 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
>
> (initramfs)

I fixed it by booting from a live CD and type in the Terminal:

> e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda1

But every few reboots i get the same error.
If someone know what cause this error and how to get it fixed permanently I'll be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

---

Well it happend again.
This is the: "e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda1" command output:

> ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda1 e2fsck 1.42
>
> (29-Nov-2011) /dev/sda1: recovering journal Error reading block
>
> 2655492 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short
>
> read).  Ignore error? yes
>
> Force rewrite? yes
>
> Clearing orphaned inode 265302 (uid=1000, gid=1000, mode=0100600,
>
> size=8192) Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes Inode 1182032,
>
> i_size is 31422, should be 40960.  Fix? yes
>
> Inode 1182032, i_blocks is 72, should be 88.  Fix? yes
>
> Pass 2: Checking directory structure Pass 3: Checking directory
>
> connectivity Pass 4: Checking reference counts Inode 1182190 ref count
>
> is 1, should be 2.  Fix? yes
>
> Unattached inode 1182583 Connect to /lost+found? yes
>
> Inode 1182583 ref count is 2, should be 1.  Fix? yes
>
> Pass 5: Checking group summary information Block bitmap differences:
>
> +595467 +595478 Fix? yes
>
> Free blocks count wrong for group #18 (29091, counted=29089). Fix? yes
>
> Free blocks count wrong (5135588, counted=5135536). Fix? yes
>
> Free inodes count wrong (1341369, counted=1341362). Fix? yes
>
> /dev/sda1:  FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED
>
> 184558 inodes used (12.09%)
>
> ```
>  107 non-contiguous files (0.1%)
>
>  188 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
>
>      # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
>
>      Extent depth histogram: 143481/16   967760 blocks used (15.86%)
>
>    0 bad blocks
>
>    1 large file
> ```
>
> 111100 regular files    18489 directories
>
> ```
>   57 character device files
>
>   25 block device files
>
>    0 fifos
>
>    2 links    54874 symbolic links (40967 fast symbolic links)
>
>    4 sockets
> ```
>
> --------   184550 files ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Please help me I don't now what more i can do.